# How to access Mongodb Object Id from React js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am building and e-commerce website.

I have Orders document in local mongodb database as shown follow:

## [image]

### How i can get _id in react Js?? Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need to populate it from your backend before for example in your case you will have

collectionName.anAction.populate(path_of_value_to_populate)

> for instance: order.findOne({_id:id}).populate("user")

replace Order collection & finOne method with yours**

then at the front end side,

you only need to access it like,

example: let suppose it's called "data" where you are receiving, it gonna be like,

> data.user._id

then you are good to go